# Unity3D: adding Multi-Tap input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multi-touch

How do you add multi-tap (not multi-touch!) input to a Unity3D game? I have a hard time finding any useful information about this.

What I got so far is multi-touch input support. this is what I'm using for that:

```
    private Vector2 _touchOrigin = -Vector2.one;

    public bool TouchEnded(int touchCount = 1)
    {
        if (Input.touchCount != touchCount) return false;
        Touch lastTouch = Input.GetTouch(touchCount - 1);
        if (lastTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            _touchOrigin = lastTouch.position;
        }
        else if (lastTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && _touchOrigin.x >= 0)
        {
            _touchOrigin.x = -1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

What I would like to do is write a similar method but for multi-tap. I.e. the user has to tap several fingers (touchCount) simultaneously a number of times (tapCount). This would be the method signature:

```
    public bool TapEnded(int touchCount = 1, int tapCount = 2)
    {
    }
```

Can somebody give me some help how to get this requirement working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Input.Touches Returns list of objects representing status of all touches during last frame. reference to link http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html

```
 void Update() {
    int fingerCount = 0;
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
            fingerCount++;

    }
    if (fingerCount > 0)
        print("User has " + fingerCount + " finger(s) touching the screen");

}
```

Comment: But that would only be about touch events, not tap events. What I need is a double-tap, or multi-tap on a specific rect area (possibly using Touch.tapCount). It should also work on Android.